# Python Pandas: if condition is true, put existing column value into new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, csv

I want to modify my pandas dataframe so if a **can** column value = 'Group Total', the **cv1** and **cvs1** values of the same row are placed in new **pv1** and **pvs1** columns for the above rows in my dataframe. If **pty_n** = 'Independent,' I'd like the pv1 and pvs1 values to be the same as the 'cv1' and 'csv1' values in the same row. Here's an illustration:

[image]

Right now, however, I am receiving something that looks like this:

[image]

```
{'rg': {0: 'Oceania', 1: 'Oceania', 2: 'Oceania', 3: 'Oceania', 4: 'Oceania', 5: 'Oceania', 6: 'Oceania', 7: 'Oceania', 8: 'Oceania', 9: 'Oceania'}, 'ctr_n': {0: 'Australia', 1: 'Australia', 2: 'Australia', 3: 'Australia', 4: 'Australia', 5: 'Australia', 6: 'Australia', 7: 'Australia', 8: 'Australia', 9: 'Australia'}, 'ctr': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: ''}, 'yr': {0: '2019', 1: '2019', 2: '2019', 3: '2019', 4: '2019', 5: '2019', 6: '2019', 7: '2019', 8: '2019', 9: '2019'}, 'mn': {0: '06', 1: '06', 2: '06', 3: '06', 4: '06', 5: '06', 6: '06', 7: '06', 8: '06', 9: '06'}, 'sub': {0: '-990', 1: '-990', 2: '-990', 3: '-990', 4: '-990', 5: '-990', 6: '-990', 7: '-990', 8: '-990', 9: '-990'}, 'cst_n': {0: 'Canberra, ACT', 1: 'Canberra, ACT', 2: 'Canberra, ACT', 3: 'Canberra, ACT', 4: 'Canberra, ACT', 5: 'Canberra, ACT', 6: 'Canberra, ACT', 7: 'Canberra, ACT', 8: 'Canberra, ACT', 9: 'Canberra, ACT'}, 'cst': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: ''}, 'can': {0: 'Ticket Votes', 1: 'SESELJA, Zed', 2: 'GUNNING, Robert', 3: 'Group Total', 4: 'Ticket Votes', 5: 'KYBURZ, Penny', 6: 'DAVIDSON, Emma', 7: 'Group Total', 8: 'Ticket Votes', 9: 'PESEC, Anthony'}, 'pty_n': {0: 'Liberal', 1: 'Liberal', 2: 'Liberal', 3: 'Liberal', 4: 'The Greens', 5: 'The Greens', 6: 'The Greens', 7: 'The Greens', 8: '\xa0', 9: '\xa0'}, 'cv1': {0: '21,209', 1: '2,142', 2: '1,001', 3: '24,352', 4: '14,637', 5: '5,719', 6: '875', 7: '21,231', 8: '1,404', 9: '3,225'}, 'cvs1': {0: '24.15', 1: '2.44', 2: '1.14', 3: '27.73', 4: '16.67', 5: '6.51', 6: '1.00', 7: '24.17', 8: '1.60', 9: '3.67'}, 'vv1': {0: '87,828', 1: '87,828', 2: '87,828', 3: '87,828', 4: '87,828', 5: '87,828', 6: '87,828', 7: '87,828', 8: '87,828', 9: '87,828'}, 'pv1': {0: '24,352', 1: '24,352', 2: '24,352', 3: '24,352', 4: '24,352', 5: '24,352', 6: '24,352', 7: '24,352', 8: '24,352', 9: '24,352'}, 'pvs1': {0: '27.73', 1: '27.73', 2: '27.73', 3: '27.73', 4: '27.73', 5: '27.73', 6: '27.73', 7: '27.73', 8: '27.73', 9: '27.73'}}
```

How can I modify my code so that the result looks like the first image, not the second? For context, this would apply to >20,000 rows within a panda dataframe, where the 'pty_n' values change without pattern (e.g., 4 rows of Liberal, 4 rows of Green, 7 rows of Labor, 2 rows of Citizen Elected, etc.) Thanks!

```
aust19 = pd.DataFrame({
'rg' : region,
'ctr_n' : ctrname,
'ctr' : ctrcode,
'yr' : year,
'mn' : month,
'sub' : sub,
'cst_n': constituencies,
'cst' : cstcode,
'can': candidates,
'pty_n': partynames,
'cv1': canvotes,
'cvs1': canshare,
'vv1': totalvotes 
})

real_pv1 = None
real_pvs1 = None

for idx, row in aust19.iloc[::-1].iterrows():
    if row.can == "Group Total":
        real_pv1 = row.cv1
        real_pvs1 = row.cvs1
    else:
        aust19.loc[idx].pv1 = real_pv1
        aust19.loc[idx].pvs1 = real_pvs1

    aust19['pv1'] = real_pv1
    aust19['pvs1'] = real_pvs1
    
aust19.to_csv("austtbd.csv")
```

Comment: can you provide your dataframe as text? just `print(df.head(10).to_dict())` and paste the output into your main body then format it as code.

Comment: @Manakin Updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general pattern I use for this kind of thing is:

`dataframe.loc[condition, destination columns] = dataframe.loc[condition, source columns]`

This takes advantage of vectorized pandas operators

More specifically, for your use-case this can be accomplished in two steps, something like:

`aust19.loc[aust19["can"] == "Group Total", ["pv1", "pvs1"]] = aust19.loc[aust19["can"] == "Group Total", ["cv1", "cvs1"]]`

`aust19.loc[aust19["pty_n"] == "Independent", ["pv1", "pvs1"]] = aust19.loc[aust19["pty_n"] == "Independent", ["cv1", "cvs1"]]`

EDIT:

I was able to accomplish this in multiple passes of the dataframe to meet the conditions

```
aust19 = pd.DataFrame({'rg': {0: 'Oceania', 1: 'Oceania', 2: 'Oceania', 3: 'Oceania', 4: 'Oceania', 5: 'Oceania', 6: 'Oceania', 7: 'Oceania', 8: 'Oceania', 9: 'Oceania'}, 'ctr_n': {0: 'Australia', 1: 'Australia', 2: 'Australia', 3: 'Australia', 4: 'Australia', 5: 'Australia', 6: 'Australia', 7: 'Australia', 8: 'Australia', 9: 'Australia'}, 'ctr': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: ''}, 'yr': {0: '2019', 1: '2019', 2: '2019', 3: '2019', 4: '2019', 5: '2019', 6: '2019', 7: '2019', 8: '2019', 9: '2019'}, 'mn': {0: '06', 1: '06', 2: '06', 3: '06', 4: '06', 5: '06', 6: '06', 7: '06', 8: '06', 9: '06'}, 'sub': {0: '-990', 1: '-990', 2: '-990', 3: '-990', 4: '-990', 5: '-990', 6: '-990', 7: '-990', 8: '-990', 9: '-990'}, 'cst_n': {0: 'Canberra, ACT', 1: 'Canberra, ACT', 2: 'Canberra, ACT', 3: 'Canberra, ACT', 4: 'Canberra, ACT', 5: 'Canberra, ACT', 6: 'Canberra, ACT', 7: 'Canberra, ACT', 8: 'Canberra, ACT', 9: 'Canberra, ACT'}, 'cst': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: ''}, 'can': {0: 'Ticket Votes', 1: 'SESELJA, Zed', 2: 'GUNNING, Robert', 3: 'Group Total', 4: 'Ticket Votes', 5: 'KYBURZ, Penny', 6: 'DAVIDSON, Emma', 7: 'Group Total', 8: 'Ticket Votes', 9: 'PESEC, Anthony'}, 'pty_n': {0: 'Liberal', 1: 'Liberal', 2: 'Liberal', 3: 'Liberal', 4: 'The Greens', 5: 'The Greens', 6: 'The Greens', 7: 'The Greens', 8: '\xa0', 9: '\xa0'}, 'cv1': {0: '21,209', 1: '2,142', 2: '1,001', 3: '24,352', 4: '14,637', 5: '5,719', 6: '875', 7: '21,231', 8: '1,404', 9: '3,225'}, 'cvs1': {0: '24.15', 1: '2.44', 2: '1.14', 3: '27.73', 4: '16.67', 5: '6.51', 6: '1.00', 7: '24.17', 8: '1.60', 9: '3.67'}, 'vv1': {0: '87,828', 1: '87,828', 2: '87,828', 3: '87,828', 4: '87,828', 5: '87,828', 6: '87,828', 7: '87,828', 8: '87,828', 9: '87,828'}, 'pv1': {0: '24,352', 1: '24,352', 2: '24,352', 3: '24,352', 4: '24,352', 5: '24,352', 6: '24,352', 7: '24,352', 8: '24,352', 9: '24,352'}, 'pvs1': {0: '27.73', 1: '27.73', 2: '27.73', 3: '27.73', 4: '27.73', 5: '27.73', 6: '27.73', 7: '27.73', 8: '27.73', 9: '27.73'}})

# convert from string
aust19['cv1'] = aust19['cv1'].str.replace(",","").astype(int)
aust19['cvs1'] = aust19['cvs1'].str.replace(",","").astype(float)
aust19['pv1'] = aust19['pv1'].str.replace(",","").astype(int)
aust19['pvs1'] = aust19['pvs1'].str.replace(",","").astype(float)

# set cache to zero
cv1_sum = 0.
cvs1_sum = 0.
group = 0
aust19['group_n'] = None

for i in aust19.index:

    # Ignore rows that are Independent
    if aust19.loc[i, "pty_n"] != "Independent":
        
        # For group totals, write the cache and reset to zero
        if  aust19.loc[i, "can"] == "Group Total":
            aust19.loc[i, "pv1"] = cv1_sum 
            aust19.loc[i, "pvs1"] = cvs1_sum 
            aust19.loc[i, "group_n"] = group
            cv1_sum = 0
            cv1s_sum = 0
            group += 1 # increment group
        
        
        # For non group totals, add the current row to the cache
        else:
            cv1_sum += aust19.loc[i, "cv1"]
            cvs1_sum += aust19.loc[i, "cvs1"]
            aust19.loc[i, "group_n"] = group

## Second pass
aust19['group_n'] = aust19['group_n'].astype(int)
for g in range(group):
    
    aust19.loc[(aust19["group_n"] == g) & (aust19["can"] != "Group Total"), "pv1"] = int(aust19.loc[(aust19["group_n"] == g) & (aust19["can"] == "Group Total"), "pv1"])
    aust19.loc[(aust19["group_n"] == g) & (aust19["can"] != "Group Total"), "pvs1"] = float(aust19.loc[(aust19["group_n"] == g) & (aust19["can"] == "Group Total"), "pvs1"])


# handle independents
aust19.loc[aust19["pty_n"] == "Independent", ["pv1", "pvs1"]] = aust19.loc[aust19["pty_n"] == "Independent", ["cv1", "cvs1"]]
```

Comment: This is helpful! For the first step, is there a way I can apply the corresponding "pv1" and "pvs1" values to "cv1" and "cvs1" for all rows above "Group Total," not just the row with "Group Total"? For example, how '666' and '0.7' are applied to all rows above the 'Rise Up Australia' group total in the image above?

Comment: just to clarify: for ALL rows above Group Total (with the same party?) or all rows above up until the previous "Group Total"

Comment: Also, as the previous commenter @Manakin mentioned, please provide an example snippet of your dataset, not just an image. You'll find that you get many more responses when people can re-create your dataset and not transcribe it from an image.

Comment: All rows above until the previous "Group Total," as there are multiple instances of the same party that have different group totals. I am running the code to create an example snippet right now, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Updated! @alex_danielssen

Comment: I'm receiving this error: 

aust19['pv1'] = aust19['pv1'].str.replace(",","").astype(int) in __getitem_ indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key) in get_loc raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'pv1'

Comment: ` KeyError: 'pv1'` usually means that `aust19` doesn't have a 'pv1' column.